# What are some common exit pressures for liquid propellant engines?

Tags: engine-design, liquid-fuel, nozzle, pressure

Most engines are overexpanded at launch so that they reach peak efficiency at altitude. It’s easy to find values for thrust, specific impulse, expansion ratio, chamber pressure, etc, but I’m trying to find specific values for the pressure at the exit of the nozzle of working engines. Stats on any engine would be great, but I’m especially looking for data on RP1/LOX engines.

Comment: If you know the chamber pressure and area ratio you can easily calculate an approximate value using the isentropic flow tables.